# Creating hover accordion using jquery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I was creating an accordion but it doesn't work well with the query part..what could be the possible cause of this?..

here's the code in jquery part..
i just copied it from one of the tutorials available in the internet and tried it but it does not work..=(

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion > li").click(function(){

        if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
        }
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').show();
});
```

I appreciate any help..thanks ahead!..=)

Comment: Are you sure that is the right example you posted? Anyway, have you had a look at jQuery UIs Accordion widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#hoverintent ?

Comment: @Andy sorry, it's not the right code, i had it posted in fiddle but it seems that the previous content were the ones still posted instead..i'm sorry, i'll just edit it then..^^

Comment: Here's my jquery code..i just copied it to one of the tutorials in the internet and tried it but it does not work...$("#accordion > li").click(function(){

 if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
  $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
 }
 $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use some already working solutions, like jquery-ui? Here is link to documentation and examples: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ You should try it, works perfectly, code is simple, if you need unique style - just change css files.

Comment: another option would be twitter bootstrap collapse: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: i already got it..i just did a little revisions with the jquery code and the html code..but thanks for all the suggestions anyway..=)